# Has Any one tried in Deploying the package programatically in Azure

Tags: azure

Has Any one tried implementing deployment of Azure CSPKG deployment programmatically using Service Management REST API. Please share with me any guideline or website which explain me clearly. Especially I Want my Web ROle to deploy the Worker ROle where package is in Azure blob storage.

Comment: Are you sure the package file is in Azure Table Storage? Did you mean to say Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: Yeah it is in Blob Storage ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this article](http://www.packtpub.com/article/managing-azure-hosted-services-with-service-management-api) by Neil Mackenzie.  This covers working with the REST API to perform deployments.  Also, you could check out the code that is used under the hood by the Windows Azure PowerShell cmdlets by looking in the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/blob/master/WindowsAzurePowershell/src/Management.ServiceManagement/HostedServices/NewAzureDeployment.cs).